# questions about probabilistic primality test

Tags: prime-numbers

As usual I used online Miller-Rabin test,but there's one thing that i don't understand:   when i tested 2500 digit or so numbers it only took 1 or few minutes,but there was few numbers that took an hour or much more, or worse 2 hour 37 minutes (for 6300 digit number)and those numbers were not even a prime,could you explain these phenomena,thank you.

Comment: Which online Rabin-Miller test do you use? Can you provide the link?

Comment: it is written entirely in Javascript

Comment: please don't tell me "it" was busy

Comment: That seems really slow.  There are some faster ones out there that will take only a few milliseconds on most composites, and 6300 digits probable prime test in under 30s.  Email me for a link.  Or install Pari/gp or Perl/ntheory or SAGE and use them.  Another option:  [Paul's PRP page](http://www.mersenneforum.org/showpost.php?p=343535&postcount=73) is a Javascript web page you can use locally to run the Frobenius-Underwood test (with minimal compositeness pretests).  It should be far faster than your example times.